# What are all the reasons to get fired in Don't get fired?

Tags: dont-get-fired

In "Don't Get Fired", in the `Collections` -> `Why you got fired` menu option there are 29 different reasons to get fired, what are they all?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to the users at Reddit (macfrag, IDontKnowHowToPM, SammyFord93, darkhvn, Ruxiik and aphrowoof) for [compiling the list](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/3g6hp5/dont_get_fired_so_frustrating_but_im_hooked/)

Ways of getting fired :

1. Failed at interview
2. You didn't get work (don't take work from your bosses)
3. No more work (happens randomly)
4. No answer (don't answer the manager when they come to your desk)
5. Failed to get an internship (fail promotion as an intern)
6. Failed to get a full-time position (fail promotion twice as F.S. / C.S. position)
7. Failed to get a promotion (fail a promotion 3 times)
8. Too sick to work (performing a health draining task with 0 health)
9. Bad team management (don't give work to your team when the zzz icon appears on them)
10. Company went bankrupt (happens randomly)
11. Company secret leaked out (take multiple screenshots by clicking the camera icon)
12. Where's my desk... ? (don't log in for a day)
13. Work mistakes (happens randomly)
14. Negative Nancy (from Assistant Manager position, reply negatively 5 times to the team)
15. Got caught working two jobs (happens randomly when starting a side job)
16. Left work early (happens randomly when you click the "back" arrow to exit the app)
17. Out with Naebal! (as President, resign from your position)
18. Sudden Strike (after reaching D.G.M. tap a lot on your workers to make them work faster)
19. Bring me some nuts (gave the nuts in the package)
20. A box of doughnuts (open the box of doughnuts)
21. Airy potato chips (eat the chips)
22. Eyes are closing (fail the "Eyes are closing" challenge)
23. Who's the hottest girl (fail the "Who's the hottest girl" challenge)
24. I want Thai food tho. (fail the "I want Thai food tho." challenge)
25. Forbidden love (fail the "Forbidden love" challenge)
26. Timing is everything! (fail the "Timing is everything!" challenge)
27. No more overtime (fail the "No more overtime" challenge)
28. Back Stabbers (fail the "Back Stabbers" challenge)
29. Head out for happy hour ! (fail the "Head out for happy hour !" challenge)

Comment: Shame on #8. I guess they've never heard of [FMLA](http://www.dol.gov/whd/fmla/).

Comment: @TimS. There is no such thing in Pixel Corea.

Answer (score 2):

1. Failed at interview
2. Failed to get work
3. No more work to do
4. No answer
5. Failed to get an internship
6. Failed to get a position
7. Failed to get a promotion
8. Too sick to work
9. Team management
10. Company went broke
11. Company secret leaked out
12. Where's my desk...?
13. Work mistakes
14. Negative nancy
15. Caught doing too many side jobs
16. Left work
17. ?????
18. Sudden strike
19. ?????
20. Box of donuts
21. Airy potato chips
22. Eyes are closing
23. Who's the hottest girl
24. I want some thai food tho
25. Forbidden love
    26.---> 29  ????

Please edit any of the missing ones.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on them, like for instance 20 you could say  "Box of donuts - When you discover a box of donuts, you will get fired for opening the box".

Comment: What do you mean by 7? I've failed to be promoted many times but I haven't got this one in my collection?